# Get the text between two characters in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have tried using charindex function but unable to get it.

Text is :- Offshore/BLR/IN

i want only BLR" out of this.

please help.

Comment: _i have tried using charindex_ --> Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Is the BLR part always 3 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that what you are actually asking is how to get the text *between* the forward-slashes, you could do this easily using `CHARINDEX`.

See the following example:

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(100)
SET @Text = '- Offshore/BLR/IN'
PRINT CHARINDEX('/', @Text)
PRINT CHARINDEX('/', @Text, CHARINDEX('/', @Text) + 1)
```

This will output `11` and `15`, respectively, which shows the position of the first and second forward-slash.

The second position is found by searching the text that occurs *after* the first position.

Following this it's just a simply case of using `SUBSTRING` to extract the text from the middle of the slashes:

```
PRINT SUBSTRING(@text, CHARINDEX('/', @text) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', @text, CHARINDEX('/', @text)+ 1)  - CHARINDEX('/', @text) - 1)
```

This essentially gets the text between the first slash (+1 position to exclude the slash), to the position of the second slash minus the position of the first slash minus 1 (to remove the first slash).
This is basically:

```
PRINT SUBSTRING(@text, 11 + 1, 15 - 11 - 1)
```

Note that is the text does not contain both slashes then this code will fail.  It contains no bounds or error checking at all, and you should look to add this.